# Remove white space in a Justified Paragraph Mac version

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm searching to trim white space when use Justified Paragraph.
I'm using word 16.33 on Mac 
[image]

Comment: Which whitespace?

Comment: some lines are expand to fill the row

Comment: You may be able to reduce white space by turning on auto-hyphenation (it's unlikely to work for the dummy text you're using in your example, though, because Word doesn't have hyphenation rules for the Latin/pseudo-Latin words in it); or manually hyphenate words yourself. Otherwise, if you don't want white space to be expanded, use simple left alignment instead of justified, because this is how justified alignment works: white space is expanded so that each line exactly fills the width of the paragraph text area.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this elsewhere though it is laborious. Click on the "paragraph" icon in the "home" ribbon.  Go to the blue dot between each word in the widely spaced last line and delete, followed by a "option-space", these words will then be spaced non-justified.

Comment: I also just found a site that has an easier fix. Turn on Show/Hide (the paragraph symbol in the Home tab of the Word Ribbon) at the end of the paragraph, you'll see a an "end of line" symbol that looks like the return arrow.  Delete the arrow by backspacing it, and the end of the line will be justified.